# Does the function $f$ belong to $L^1_{loc}$ or $L^1$?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I have the following question:

> Prove that the function $x \to \dfrac{1}{x(\sqrt{x}-1)} \in L^1_{loc}(]0,+\infty[)$. This function is it in $L^1(]0,+\infty[)$?

I try to do this: first, to prove that $\dfrac{1}{x(\sqrt{x}-1)} \in L^1_{loc}(]0,+\infty[)$, we have that the function is continuous in $]0,+\infty[ / {1}$ so it is $L^1_{loc} (]0,+\infty[ / {1})$. It remains to prove that the function is integrable in the neighbourhood of $1$. So i try to prove that $\displaystyle\int_1^a \dfrac{1}{x(\sqrt{x}-1}= dx < +\infty$. But

1. I have o idea how to do this.
2. How we see il $\dfrac{1}{x(\sqrt{x}-1)} \in L^1(]0,+\infty[)$?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Note that as $x\to 1$,
$$\dfrac{1}{x(\sqrt{x}-1)}=\dfrac{(\sqrt{x}+1)}{x(x-1)}\sim\frac{2}{x-1}.$$
Is this function integrable in a neighbourhood $1$?

Comment: But if $\dfrac{1}{x(\sqrt{x}-1)} \thicksim \dfrac{1}{x-1}$ this implies that $\displaystyle\int_1^a \dfrac{1}{x(\sqrt{x}-1)} dx = \displaystyle\int_1^a \dfrac{1}{x-1}$? I dont understand the idea. Then we have $\displaystyle\int_1^a \dfrac{2}{x-1} dx = 2 \lim_{c \to 1} [\ln(x-1)]_c^a = 2 \lim_{c \to 1} (\ln(a-1)-\ln(c-1)]$ this limite is $+\infty$

Comment: No the integral are not equal, but by the comparison test $\int_1^a \dfrac{1}{x(\sqrt{x}-1)} dx$ is convergent iff $\int_1^a \dfrac{1}{x-1}dx$ is convergent.

Comment: Ok, so we have $\displaystyle\int_1^a \dfrac{1}{x-1} dx= \displaystyle\int_1^a (\ln(x-1))' dx= \lim_{c \to 1} [\ln(x-1)]_c^a= \ln(a-1)- \lim_{c \to 1} \ln(x-1)$ and this limit don't exist, beacause $\ln$ is not defined in 0.

Comment: If $a>1$ then $\int_1^a \dfrac{1}{x-1} dx=\ln(a-1)- \lim_{x \to 1^+} \ln(x-1)=+\infty$

Comment: yes that what i found, so what'is the conclusion? We compare the function with an other function who isn't integrable, so we can conclude. Non?

Comment: You said that the limit don't exist... it exists and it is $+\infty$. Therefore $\frac{1}{x-1}$ AND $\frac{1}{x(\sqrt{x}-1)}$ are NOT integrable in a neighbourhood of $1$.

Comment: So we compare $f$ with another function g. We found that $g$ isn't integrale, so conclude that $f$ is not integrable in $g$. But the choice of function $g$ is unique? there are no other choice of $g$? How we can sure that we will not fount an other function $g$ integrable which is equivalent to $f$?

Comment: They are infinite functions which are asymptotic equivalent at some point, but they all share the same integrability property.

Comment: Please have you an pdf where we fount this theorem?

Comment: See for example: http://users.math.msu.edu/users/gnagy/teaching/12-spring/mth133/L23-133.pdf

Comment: Thak you, the test theorem says that il we have $f \leq g$ then il $g$ diverge we have no information for the convergence or diverence of $f$. Then my question is how we know that there are no function $g$ convergente such that $f \leq g$? the divergence of $g$ not implies the diverence of $f$. Non?

Comment: Did you read page 6? Note that $f\sim g$ at $x_0$, iff $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)/g(x)=1$. A similar theorem holds in a neighbourhood of $x_0$ (instead of $[a,+\infty)$).

Comment: Limit Comparaison test! Ok, thank you so much